# Probability of a given difference in draws from uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose the random variable $X$ is distributed uniformly over $[0,a]$.

Define $Z$ as the difference between the two greatest draws. $N$ draws are taken.

Then, the text book defines  the probability of a given value of $z$ is defined as $$p(Z=z) = \frac{n(a-z)^{n-1} }{a^n}$$

It then asks what $p(z)$ would be if the random variable $X$ is distributed uniformly over $[b,c]$, where $b,c$ are positive numbers. What would this be?

---

This is my best guess:

$$p(Z=z) = \frac{n(c-b-z)^{n-1} }{(c-b)^n}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is okay.

That is the effect of a shift in the support of the random variable on the probability density function for the difference between the two highest order statistics from the samples (which $p$ should be)$.